# spring boot+mysql+docker+travis when building in travis getting mysql connection failre

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

am new to docker. I have configured spring boot with mysql and wrote docker and docker compose like below. I gave docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build in my local, and it works fine in local. When I push it to GIT and when travis picks it up I get below exception in travis logs. I think it is not able to connect to mysql.

```
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | 2020-11-05T15:41:27.929272Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | 2020-11-05T15:41:27.938951Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | 2020-11-05T15:41:27.939205Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | Version: '5.7.32'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:27.949  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:27.950  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | 2020-11-05 15:41:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:28.644  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:28.645  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2615 ms
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:28.939  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:30.199 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
```

**My travis.yml**

```
sudo: required
language: generic

services:
  - docker
script:
  - mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
```

**dockerfile**

```
From openjdk:8
ADD target/docker-mk.war docker-mk.war
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "docker-mk.war"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-standalone:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h mysql-standalone -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
  springboot-docker-container:
    image: springboot-docker-container
    ports:
      - 8089:8085
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
         - mysql-standalone
               


Anything am missing or doing wrong here?
```

Answer (score 0):

`-depends-on: mysql-startalong` only makes sure that mysql container is started before spring boot container, but don't makes sure that mysql server is ready to connect.

If you are starting mysql with an existed database (and that's probably the case on your local machine, because the volumn containing the mysql data is not cleared everytime unless you explictly do it), everything should be fine;

but if mysql is starting from scratch (that's the cases on travis), mysql needs some time to initialize accounts, database, configurations etc., and trying to connect during this leads to an error.

Let's take a look at your log,

```
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | 2020-11-05 15:41:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:28.644  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:28.645  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2615 ms
    springboot-docker-container_1_39c0a7e72bdc | 2020-11-05 15:41:28.939  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    mysql-standalone_1_3deba3f11bd1 | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

while your spring application starts initializing, mysql has just started a temporary server and is still reading timezone settings. So a connection failure is raised.

As for solutions, here is a example from [docker documention](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for Postgres.

Also, you can check the port using netcat(remember to install it in the dockerfile) in an entrypoint file like this:

```sh
#!bin/sh

echo "Waiting for database..."
while ! nc -z DATABASE_HOST DATABASE_PORT; do
    sleep 0.5
done
echo "Database started."

java -jar YOURFILE

exec "$@"
```